# HTML5 Drag and Drop специальные события именно для Drag’n’Drop переноса

Tags: javascript, html5

при изучении js наткнулся на такое: **мобильные устройства плохо поддерживают специальные события именно для Drag’n’Drop и возникли вопросы**

1. насколько плохо?))
2. если у сайта будет мобильная версия реализовать drag-and-drop с помощью специальных событий Drag’n’Drop или же реализовать самому с помощью mousedown -> mousemove -> mouseup или как то ешё

Comment: В мобильном мире нету mousedown -> mousemove -> mouseup. Потому что нету мышки :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko черт))) спс не знал остаются только специальные события Drag’n’Drop? или все же есть альтернатива?

Comment: @Armen тач события https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: @МихаилКамахин спс